# mysqli_real_escape_string() adds slashes on database insert

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a form and passing the information through $_POST into a database and I'm using mysqli_real_escape before upload but it is adding a slash to the uploaded text. Here is my code:

```
$type = "new";
$subtype = "news";
$title = ucwords(strtolower($_POST["title"]));
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $title);
$article = $_POST["article"];
$article = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $article);

$insert_news_sql = "INSERT INTO news.....
```

If I add something like "We're trying something new" to the title, it uploads "We/re trying something new" - How can I prevent the slashes being added to the database?

Comment: use stripslahses() to remove slashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to remove slashes always use stripslashes..

```
$title = ucwords(strtolower(stripslashes($_POST["title"])));
$article = stripslashes($_POST["article"]);
```

Comment: Thanks - But what about all the issues involving SQL INjection? That's what made me strip using stripslashes in the first place and use real_escape

Comment: use can use trim,stiplslashes, htmlspecial characters to prevent sql injection or you can create your own function like this [function Sanitize($str,$remove_nl=true)
    {
        $str = $this->StripSlashes($str);

        if($remove_nl)
        {
            $injections = array('/(\n+)/i',
                '/(\r+)/i',
                '/(\t+)/i',
                '/(%0A+)/i',
                '/(%0D+)/i',
                '/(%08+)/i',
                '/(%09+)/i'
                );
            $str = preg_replace($injections,'',$str);
        }

        return $str;
    }]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are using an older version of PHP and have magic quotes enabled. See [here](http://www.php.net/magic_quotes). With magic quotes on your POST variables are automatically mysql escaped, so calling mysql_real_escape_string on then will cause double escaping, which is the reason why you get the backslashes in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Are they really in the Database or are you just looking at the escaped string?

When creating new applications, you should not use mysql_* functions anymore. Instead, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

Comment: Yes they are really in the database